# How can i find out what jQuery is causing the low scrolling performance? Scrolling lags

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll

I have built a site, where there is a lot of jQuery/javascript, but i do not think there is too much compared to other sites.

Try the site here and the scrolling (only html output so you do not have to create an account): http://www.fitlab.dk/fitlab.htm

It is in Chrome it is really bad, compared to Firefox where the performance is better, stange because I also thought Chrome had the best javascript performance.

**But how can know what is causing the scrolling to be slow?**

I tried remove jQuery "extensions" one by one, so I could tell which what causing the problem, but I could not find the problem.

I know Chrome has this where you can test the CPU, what processes use how much power.

Here is an screenshot of the final results where i have scrolled a lot and recorded it:
[image: CPU Performance]

That do not give a lot of information, it actually do not know what to use that information for :-/

I would be really glad if somebody would help me, thank you! :-)

Comment: offtopic: nice background! http://www.fitlab.dk/images/roadbg.jpg
ontopic: have you tried yslow? http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

Comment: Try removing background images and then scroll. See it that's better.

Comment: scrolling goes fast in opera... and nice webpage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing all the CSS and see if the performance improves. I have seen scrolling lag when large background images are there, especially when the background is fixed.

Also could you try removing one jquery plugin at a time to find out if any plugin is causing the issue?

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for your reply! The background is insertet by jquery, because if it where in the CSS file, i caused major performance issue. I have tried removing one by one of the jquery plugins, but it could not see any differens, i will try again! But arent there a way to benchmark and test what jquery is taking to much power?

Comment: If you look at fitlab.dk/fitlab.htm it is only the jquery Flot which is left, and i think it is that which is causing the problem! But it is still slow with the background removed!

Comment: It feels much smoother for me. Last time I checked, I could see it struggle. Now it is pretty good both in Chrome and IE 9.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fitlab.dk%2Ffitlab.htm

```
Line 238, Column 9: Stray end tag div.
```

Comment: What does it mean to stray and tag? I google it, and it did not give me a good answer. But i guess it means a lose end? A </div> to much?

Comment: Yes. A closing tag without matching start tag.